# Removing whitespace before the itemize symbol

Tags: formatting, enumerate, enumitem

I wonder how to remove whitespace before itemize symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `wide` option is here for that. Your options `[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]` is equivalent to the shortest `[nosep]`. Here are three variants: you can have the left margin of the list coincide with the text left margin (default) or with the beginning of the text of the item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide]
  \item First Item
  \item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt]
  \item First Item
  \item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide, leftmargin=*]
  \item First Item
  \item Second Item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The bullet is by default indented by `\parindent`, but you may change it setting `wide=some length`.

Answer (score 4):

In the options of the itemize environment you could use `labelindent=0cm` and `leftmargin=0cm` to get rid of `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`; and if you want the bullet to be aligned with the text, add `wide` to the options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[nosep,wide,labelindent=0cm,leftmargin=0cm]
  \item First Item
  \item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But in this way the item symbols go out of the text margin, add some text rows before and/or after your itemize to see it...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I have edited my answer to take into account your comment, thanks